# Generate Dynamic ng-model for form Control in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Array in my controller. On the basis of that Array I'm generating Input fields On my page.

My AngularJs code

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.names = ['morpheus', 'neo', 'trinity'];
});
```

And on page I'm generating my input fields

```
<form name="myForm1" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
     <div ng-repeat="gg in names">
       <input type="text" ng-model="control[index]"/>
     </div>
     <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Now it generating `ng-model` for each textbox are `control[index]`

but I want to generate ng-model for each textbox like

```
control[0]
control[1]
control[2]
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UWQKK6zM1KJzZRVeTlPq?p=preview)

Comment: You need to use `$index` to refer to index. But, you should know that your "model" _is_ your array of `names`. Are you trying to create a copy of the model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use

```
<input type="text" ng-model="control[$index]"/>
```

and there is no scope variable called `control` so you need to define the scope variable also, as below

```
$scope.control = {};
```

here is the updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zcpoqhOayB6JZANZLFTP?p=preview)